# how to create password expiry validation in JSP login page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to know to where I must embed the following code snippets to get the application work in my JSP servlet project?..Further I'm using the MVC architecture..and need to know whether it is correct or not because I'm new to jsp.

```
public class PsswordSerializability {

private java.util.Date lastSignupdate;

public boolean isExpired(String password){

    boolean check = false;

    //Date lastSignupdate = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(lastSignupdate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 45);

    java.util.Date expirationDate = cal.getTime();

    if(lastSignupdate < expirationDate){
        System.out.println("reset password");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("success");

}
    return check;
}}
```

above is the code for the logic that I need to execute (password should reset after 45 days and prompt a dialogue box). Then below is the jsp code for sql query part.

```
<form>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="oldpwd" placeholder="Old Password">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="password" name="newpwd" placeholder="New Password">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="password" name="cnfrmpwd" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="RESET">

                    <%
                        String oldpass = request.getParameter("password");
                        String newpass = request.getParameter("newpwd");
                        String conpass = request.getParameter("cnfrmpwd");
                        String username = request.getParameter("username");
                        Connection con;
                        ResultSet rs = null;
                        try {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospitalmanagementsystemdb");
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM com.hospitalsystem.dao.UserDAO WHERE Password='" + oldpass + "'");
                            rs = ps.executeQuery();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                username = rs.getString(1);
                                newpass = rs.getString(2);
                            }

                            if (oldpass!=null&&newpass!=null&&newpass.equals(oldpass)) {
                                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE com.hospitalsystem.dao.UserDAO SET Password='" + newpass + "' where Username='" + username + "'");


                            ps1.executeUpdate();
        %>



                    <p>Password has been Reset</p>

                    <%response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); %>

                    <% } else {%>

                    <p>Password change failed. Try again!</p>

                    <% }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            out.println(e);
                        }
                    %>



            </div>
```

I don't know which code should I used as servlet and other. Please describe what has to be done in here.

Comment: You should use sessions, an object that will contain all the user data while he is connected to server. you could give it an expire date (days/hours etc..) and react accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends up to the requirement.... If you want the password to be expired . No matter your site is Idle or not then.

1. First start a timer as soon as you logged in.
2. Use Context listener which ll be called in every request and it will check if the time is more then defined time.
3. If time exceeds then force log out.

**Case 2:**

Else you can use session if you want password to be invalidate after certain time period if your logged is user is idle .

For the session follow below steps

In web.xml you need to add below code..

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Then set session as soon as you logged in ....

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("userName", "Tom");
```

You can take any time for the session to be expired . If the time will exceed more then 30 minutes then session will be expired automatically . You need to just check .

```
if(session.getAttribute("userName")==null)
{
    // log out 
}
```

Hope you ll understand now.

Comment: thank you Gokul, but what happen when it need to expire password in number of days like in 30 days? can it be handle by sessions?

Comment: Then you should better to use first option where you need to compare in days.